# Confidence/Credible intervals implying that estimated mean from sample is equal to population mean in expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value, bayesian, confidence-interval

I need some help understanding the fallacy in the following reasoning (thank you in advance!). It is essentially implying that for a single sample from a population, you can know a population parameter (like the EV) precisely with a few seemingly reasonable assumptions. I’ll frame it as an example.

Let’s say that we are trying to infer something about the return distribution (assume normal) of a financial instrument (population distribution). We make an assumption about the variance of this distribution. We then create samples and calculate their averages, and each sample consists of 100 draws from the population distribution (which again we don’t know).

Using our assumption about the variance of the population distribution, we can calculate the variance of the sampling distribution, which is the distribution which results after sampling (again, each sample being of 100 draws from the population distribution and the resultant average) infinitely many times. We can compute a 95% confidence or Bayesian credible interval using the variance of the sampling distribution, which implies that if we take 1 incremental sample and calculate its average, the probability that the population mean falls within said interval around the sample average is 95% (Yes I realize frequentists will challenge this for confidence intervals, but the credible interval unequivocally states this). So, if we take an incremental sample, it would follow that the probability that the population mean falls within the band described by the confidence interval around the estimated mean of the sample is 95%.

We’ve now basically created a probability distribution for the population mean itself, and the midpoint of the distribution is the estimated sample mean. If we assume that this distribution is normally distributed or even just that the likelihood that the population mean/EV falls within the 95% confidence band around the estimated sample mean or the in the 2.5% tails on either side of the band is uniform, then that would imply that in expectation, the expected value of the population mean/EV is the estimated sample mean.

It would seem obvious that that cannot be true given it would imply that that you could then know your true EV for any population simply by referencing a sample of any size. You can’t say Steph Curry’s free throw make probability is 50% after watching him shoot 2 free throws and miss 1.

Where exactly does this go wrong?

Comment: Variance from a small sample is large.  For one sample it is infinite.   For your description, you never know the true mean only an approximation with a narrower range.

Comment: Can you clarify this comment? "in expectation, the expected value of the population mean/EV is the estimated sample mean."

Comment: @herbsteinberg what do you mean the variance is infinite?

Comment: @user469053 Basically by saying there is a 95% chance that the population mean falls within a certain band around the sample mean, it seems like we are creating a probability distribution for the population mean itself. Taking the EV of this distribution would seem to be the same as assessing the population mean in expectation.

Comment: We create a sampling distribution. It sounds like you're treating the expected value of the sample mean as a synonym for the estimated sample mean. But those aren't the same. The sample mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a random variable, and as such it has a mean (same as the mean of the population). But this isn't the same as observing values $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and averaging those. The latter is an observed value of a random variable. Not its mean.

Comment: I'm not conflating the two. Can you please point out which specific step in the scenario described is illogical/incorrect? The definitions of these intervals imply that if you take ONE incremental sample, the probability that the population mean falls within that interval around the sample parameter (in this case the sample mean (FOR THAT SINGLE SAMPLE) is 95%. That is literally a statement about the probability distribution of the population mean itself...

Comment: You seem to be concerned that we can know the population mean from a sample. You say that the expected value of the distribution we created is the same as the population mean.

Where in your process do we learn the expected value of the distribution we created?

Comment: Right I suppose that's maybe where it goes wrong. Calculating the expected value of the distribution we created is based on the assumption that the sample mean is the MIDPOINT of the distribution we created and that the population mean is uniformly likely to fall within the 95% confidence/credible interval or in the 5% of tails around that midpoint. Is that just a wild assumption? Literature about these intervals very often includes graphics of distributions that are shown to be normal and indicate exactly this.

Comment: Ignore midpoints. Where in your process do you learn the expected value of the distribution we created?

Comment: We can't ignore midpoints. The midpoint is the most important factor. That's the entire basis for creating the distribution. And assigning the midpoint as the sample mean is based on the statement that there is a 95% likelihood that the population mean falls within the interval AROUND it (hence it being the midpoint). Taking the EV of that distribution assuming it's normal or uniform then implies the midpoint is the EV.

Comment: Midpoints have nothing to do with the question I'm asking. The mean of an average die roll is 3.5. If I create a sample by rolling the die a few times, and I get a bunch of 1s, the midpoint of the sample I created is 1. Has nothing to do with any expected value.

Where in the process do we learn the expected value of the distribution we created?

Comment: You're not refuting what I'm saying. Why don't you explain the fallacy behind creating the distribution as I have described. The interval definition says that there is a 95% likelihood that the population mean falls within the interval around the sample mean. If that's true, we have effectively created a probability distribution for the population mean that is centered around the sample mean. What is unclear about that?

Comment: Why don't you answer my question? I will not continue to participate if you ignore the question I'm asking you. You repeatedly refer to "the expected value of the distribution we created," which is a thing that we do not and cannot know. It is not a thing that we can calculate, but you have talked about the process of calculating it. Why do you think that the expected value of the distribution we created is a thing that we can calculate?

Comment: I feel like I have answered that already, which is why I'm confused. I've explained how I'm arriving at this distribution (midpoint being the sample mean) and making an assumption of uniformity and symmetry about the values around this midpoint. Given the midpoint and those assumptions, we can calculate the expected value. Why do you disagree with that?

Comment: What do you mean by "uniformity" about the midpoint? Do you mean "symmetry"?

Comment: Yes symmetry. Sorry I edited the comment to include the word symmetry but may have been after you read it.

Comment: If you consider a distribution which is symmetric about the observed sample mean (and not that there are many such distributions, not all of which have finite expected value), then the mean of that distribution (if it's finite) will be equal to the sample mean. But there's no reason why the sample mean has to equal the population mean. In fact, for the normal distribution, there is zero probability that the sample mean equals the population mean.

At no point do we learn the population distribution from the sample or from the constructed intervals.

Comment: The distribution in question here is a probability distribution for the population mean, so if that's true, obviously we learn can lean something about the population mean from it. The expected value of this distribution (which you just conceded is equal to the sample mean if we make the assumption of symmetry) IS the expected value of the population mean.

Comment: If you examine the formula for estimated variance, there is a factor 1/(n-1) where n is the number of samples.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ with finite mean. That random variable has some distribution.

For a fixed $n$ and iid samples $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ from the distribution of $X$, we can construct the random variable $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, which has its own distribution (possibly) distinct from the distribution of $X$. When you talk about the distribution we created from the sample, it doesn't sound like you're talking about this distribution.

If we observe actual values $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, we can construct the empirical distribution, which has cdf $F(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1(x\leqslant x_i)$, where $1(x_i\leqslant x)=1$ if $x\leqslant x_i$ and $1(x_i\leqslant x)=0$ otherwise. This is also (possibly) distinct from the two previous distributions. When you talk about the distribution we created from the sample, it doesn't sound like you're talking about this distribution.

If we finally take the observed sample mean $\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and select some distribution which is symmetric about $\overline{x}$ (note that there are many such distributions), we get another distribution which is generally not equal to any of the previous three. When you talk about the distribution that we created from the sample, based on your comments, it sounds like you're talking about one of these distributions. But knowing this distribution doesn't tell us the population distribution (or the other two preceding distributions).

The fact that the confidence interval is symmetric about the sample mean doesn't mean that the population distribution (or the distribution of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ or the empirical distribution) is symmetric about the sample mean. For example, if we have a normal population with mean $0$ and we pick a sample which has sample mean $1$, the population distribution is still symmetric around $0$, not $1$. The confidence interval we construct is symmetric about $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand most of what you've said; for example you say

> We make an assumption about the variance of this distribution (let’s call said assumption sigma 1)

but then you never state what this assumption is, only that you've made it (?). Do you mean that you're assuming that the variance is equal to $\sigma_1^2$?

You also use three different terms "estimated sample mean," "population mean," and "estimated mean," and I don't know what these are supposed to be referring to. I see (at least) three different means here and this is what I would call them:

- The true mean $\mathbb{E}(X)$ of the distribution being sampled from; is this what you mean by "population mean"?
- The sample mean $\frac{X_1 + \dots + X_n}{n}$; is this what you mean by "estimated sample mean" or is this something else?
- The expected sample mean $\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{X_1 + \dots + X_n}{n} \right) = \mathbb{E}(X)$, which equals the true mean. I don't know when if ever you're referring to this.

> then that would imply that in expectation, the expected value of the population mean/EV is the estimated sample mean.

I don't understand most of what you've said in this paragraph, and I especially don't understand this sentence; here it sounds like "population mean" now means the sample mean, but now I don't know what you mean by "estimated sample mean"; if you mean the expected sample mean then this sentence is a tautology, but I don't know what else you could mean. (My sincere apologies for using the word "mean" so many times there!)

> it would imply that that you could then know your true EV for any population simply by referencing a sample of any size.

Since I don't even understand what terms you're using, nor do I understand what argument you have in mind because of that, it's not at all obvious to me that anything you've said implies this. You are of course correct that obviously you cannot do this. As user 469053 appears to be suggesting in the comments, maybe you're confusing the sample mean with the expected sample mean; it is true that the expected sample mean is the true mean but you never learn the expected sample mean by sampling, only the sample mean, so there's no contradiction here.

---

I don't understand anything about frequentist statistics so here is how I would set things up in a Bayesian way. We take samples from a normal distribution of known variance $\sigma$ but unknown mean $\mu$ which we want to estimate. Given $n$ samples $X_1, \dots X_n$ from this distribution we can compute the log likelihood for observing our sample given a particular mean $\mu$, which is proportional to

$$- \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2.$$

The [maximum likelihood estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) for the mean $\mu$ is then the value of $\mu$ that minimizes this sum of squares, which is classically known to be given by the sample mean

$$\mu_{MLE} = \frac{X_1 + \dots + X_n}{n}.$$

More generally, given a prior on $\mu$ we can consider the [maximum a posteriori estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) instead. The MLE estimate corresponds to a uniform prior over all values of $\mu$ which is an [improper prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors).

Instead of just considering the MLE we can consider the entire posterior distribution over possible values of $\mu$ given our sample, which (starting from the improper uniform prior) is a Gaussian with mean $\mu_{MLE}$. So the posterior mean, mode, and median are all equal to $\mu_{MLE}$. Now $\mu_{MLE}$ is itself a random variable, and it has the same mean as the distribution being sampled from, namely the unknown $\mu_{\text{True}}$. But again, we never learn this mean because we only ever get a *specific* sample; we can only compute $\mu_{MLE}$ and whatever else we want to compute from our specific sample.

Comment: Apologies for the inconsistency of terms. I used sample mean and estimated sample mean interchangeably to describe the 2nd bulleted mean you gave. I use population mean/EV to described the 1st bulleted mean you gave. I didn't reference the expected sample mean (the 3rd bulleted mean you gave), but I fully recognize that it is equal to the population mean.

Comment: The only other "distribution" I'm referring to is that which is being "described" by the confidence interval. The confidence interval is telling us that there is a 95% chance that the population mean lies within that interval around the sample mean. Given that, it doesn't seem unreasonable to say that we now have a probability distribution for the population mean itself, with the sample mean as the midpoint. If you then assume symmetry on either side of that midpoint, the expected value of the population mean would be the midpoint, which is the sample mean. That's the confusion.

Comment: @Marco: I again will discuss this in Bayesian language only. As I've said above, you can compute a posterior distribution for the true mean / population mean given the sample; with the above hypotheses it is Gaussian, so in particular it has the same mean, median, and mode, and is symmetric about this mean, which is the sample mean $\mu_{MLE}$. So what's the confusion? One thing that is tricky here is that the posterior distribution is a "random probability distribution," since it itself depends on the sample $X_i$ which consists of random variables. So there are two levels of randomness.

Comment: I think you would benefit from trying to use some mathematical notation to write down all the statements you're making instead of using only English because it would force you to be clearer about exactly what mean you're referring to when, and which expectations you're taking when (since there are two levels of randomness and we can take expectations with respect to either or both of them).